# Disposable objects lifetime when closing WinForm application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dispose

I have a windows forms application which connects to a database. All heavy duty SQL queries are implemented in background threads so that they do not block the main thread. Some of those queries require a database transaction. All Db objects are initialized with using keyword to ensure proper disposal:

```
using (conn = OpenConnection())
{
    using (tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Now, some users are inpatient and they just close the application while the application has an active transaction in a background thread. Our DB admins discovered that those transactions are still active on the database for another few minutes or even longer which is a problem since open transaction locks data.

So, what happens with threads and disposable objects within those threads when user decides to close the application? Threads are created using `Task.StartNew()` methods.

Comment: It depends how do they close the application; if users do it with kill process or commands alike you can't do anything. If, however, the application is closed by closing the main window you may wait for threads to finish.

Comment: These are ordinary users, they are closing the main form.

Comment: 'Threads are created using Task.StartNew()' - nope, you are not creating threads, the TPL might be creating threads, but it could also re-use them.

Comment: Agreed, but they are always background threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tasks

[Foreground and Background Threads:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> a background thread does not keep the managed execution environment running. Once all foreground threads have been stopped in a managed process (where the .exe file is a managed assembly), the system stops all background threads and shuts down.

This also applies to threads from thread pool that are used by default when starting new task without specyfing other option:

[Task Schedulers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The default task scheduler is based on the .NET Framework 4 ThreadPool

[Foreground and Background Threads:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Threads that belong to the managed thread pool (that is, threads whose IsThreadPoolThread property is true) are background threads.

## Facts about application termination

After that, I haven't found any further information what is going on out there after thread termination. What I did, is simple test instead:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Method);
    Task.Delay(1000);
}

static void Method()
{
    try
    {
        while (true) { }
    }
    finally
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Polygon\Test.txt", "test");
    }
}
```

The answer is, that **finally block was not executed**.

## Solutions

### ThreadAbortException - not here

There are features in .NET like [ThreadAbortException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) called as answer for thread termination, but:

> When the common language runtime (CLR) stops background threads after all foreground threads in a managed executable have ended, it does not use Thread.Abort.

### Process.Exited event - not here

In case, when you run other process, you could use the following code:

```
var myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(CleanUp);
```

But this also doesn't work in case of current process.

### AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit - works

However the solution suggested by [Avneesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3718277/avneesh) works for current process well:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CleanUp;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(Method);
    Task.Delay(1000);
}

static void Method()
{
    try
    {
        while (true) { }
    }
    finally
    {
        CleanUp(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

static void CleanUp(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Polygon\Test.txt", "test");
}
```

## Process termination

The answer for question what happens with rosources can be found in [Terminating a Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article:

> - Any remaining threads in the process are marked for termination.
> - **Any resources allocated by the process are freed.**
> - All kernel objects are closed.
> - The process code is removed from memory.
> - The process exit code is set.
> - The process object is signaled.

And How Processes are Terminated:

> - Any thread of the process calls the ExitProcess function. Note that some implementation of the C run-time library (CRT) call ExitProcess if the primary thread of the process returns.
> - **The last thread of the process terminates**.
> - Any thread calls the TerminateProcess function with a handle to the process.
> - For console processes, the default console control handler calls ExitProcess when the console receives a CTRL+C or CTRL+BREAK signal.
> - The user shuts down the system or logs off.

## DB Connection

Connection is a resource so if processed is terminated, all its resources are freed. I checked how it looks like in practice.

C# code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=[database_name];Integrated Security=True");
connection.Open();
Debugger.Launch();
connection.Close();
connection.Dispose();
```

T-SQL query for sessions lookup:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE nt_user_name = '[user_name]' AND program_name = '.Net SqlClient Data Provider'
```

I've noticed that for each new connection, new session was created. The funniest thing was, that session was not freed after explicitely closing nor disposing the connection. But - what is currently in our field of interest - **session was freed when application process was terminated**.

Comment: Yep, adding a `try { ... } finally { ... }` sort of prevents the current thread from being aborted.

Comment: So, what happens with objects when thread stops? What happens to resources which where held (file handlers, db connections, etc..)?

Comment: @Nezreli I will add any further information to my answer

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Your answer suggests that Db transaction and Db connection will not be disposed when terminating process so the database driver is unaware that the process is no more. I'll have to test this.

Comment: @Nezreli I was curious too and checked this. It looks like a session is closed after process termination. So maybe the issue lies in foreground threads that keep process alive.

Comment: Thanks for this. This behavior is probably the implementation detail in managed driver for SQL server. I'm having an issue with IBM Informix managed driver. It looks like I'll have to track all active connections and transactions for cleanup purposes.

Comment: Connections are usually pooled. Disposing a connection in this case merely returns the connection to the pool.

Answer (score 1):

When the application is shut down, the Task.StartNew threads will die as the process itself has exited. What you can do is hook on to the  processExit event and then either wait for few more seconds or try to tell the task using some broadcast to clean themselves.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;
```